# How can I solve the question that roles cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final String roles[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roles);

    }
```

> roles cannot be resolved or is not a field in the r.ava file;
>
> Roles cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this statement:

```
final String roles[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roles);
```

It should be like this:

```
final String[] roles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you have string array in `arrays.xml` or in `strings.xml` file?

First of all you should create an `arrays.xml` file in `res` folder, then create a string array in it. 
For example:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="roles">
       <item>Item1</item>
       <item>Item2</item>
       <item>Item3</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then you can use it in your application

```
String roles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roles)
```